# Parsing correct type value to a list in Java

Tags: java, csv, parsing

First of all, I apologize because I am not sure I even know how to phrase my problem exactly. We have just started Object oriented programming in Uni and I'm having trouble with grasping the concept.

So the goal is to work get data from a .csv file. ( Periodic table )

The problem is that in the original file some fields are just empty. I am aware of the problem ( at least I think so) :  The fileReader saves them as empty strings in to the array, and they get parsed in to my array list as a strings, while a type Double is expected. But I just don't know what to do.

```
: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:549)
    at ChemicalElement.DAO.<clinit>(DAO.java:28)
```

I'm posting all the code I have in case there's something else wrong that I'm not aware of. All criticism (or advice) is welcome!

```java
public class ChemicalElement {
    private String element;
    private int number;
    private String symbol;
    private double weight;
    private double boil;
    private double melt;
    private double density;
    private double vapour;
    private double fusion;

    public ChemicalElement()
    {

    }
    public String GetElement()
    {
        return this.element;
    }
    public int GetNumber()
    {
        return this.number;
    }
    public String GetSymbol()
    {
        return this.symbol;
    }
    public double GetWeight()
    {
        return this.weight;
    }
    public double GetBoil()
    {
        return this.boil;
    }
    public  double GetMelt()
    {
        return this.melt;
    }
    public double GetDensity()
    {
        return this.density;
    }
    public double GetVapour()
    {
        return this.vapour;
    }
    public double GetFusion()
    {
        return this.fusion;
    }
    public void SetElement(String element)
    {
        this.element = element;
    }
    public void SetNumber(int number)
    {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public void SetSymbol(String symbol)
    {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }
    public void SetWeight(double weight)
    {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    public void SetBoil(double boil)
    {
        this.boil = boil;
    }
    public void SetMelt(int melt)
    {
        this.melt = melt;
    }
    public void SetDensity(int density)
    {
        this.density = density;
    }
    public void SetVapour(double vapour)
    {
        this.vapour = vapour;
    }
    public void SetFusion(double fusion)
    {
        this.fusion = fusion;
    }
    public ChemicalElement(String element ,int number,String symbol, double weight, double boil,double melt , double density, double vapour, double fusion)
    {
        this.element = element;
        this.number = number;
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.boil = boil;
        this.melt = melt;
        this.density = density;
        this.vapour = vapour;
        this.fusion = fusion;
    }
    public ChemicalElement(String element ,int number,String symbol, double weight, double boil,double melt , double density, double vapour)
    {
        this.element = element;
        this.number = number;
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.boil = boil;
        this.melt = melt;
        this.density = density;
        this.vapour = vapour;
    }
    public ChemicalElement(String element ,int number,String symbol, double weight)
    {
        this.element = element;
        this.number = number;
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Element{" + element + ", number= " + number + ", symbol= " + symbol + ", weight= " + weight + ", boil=" + ", melt= " + melt + "densitiy= " + density + ", vapour= " + vapour + "fusion= " + fusion + '}';
    }
}
```

---

```java
public class DAO {
    public static List<ChemicalElement> elements = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        try
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader("elements2.csv"));
            String firstLine = scan.nextLine(); //skip first line ( title )
            while(scan.hasNext())
            {
                String readFile[] = scan.nextLine().split(",");
                if(readFile.length == 4)
                {
                    ChemicalElement El = new ChemicalElement(readFile[0],Integer.parseInt(readFile[1]),readFile[2],Double.parseDouble(readFile[3]));
                    elements.add(El);
                }
                else if(readFile.length == 8)
                {
                    //first exception is down below
                    ChemicalElement El = new ChemicalElement(readFile[0],Integer.parseInt(readFile[1]),readFile[2],Double.parseDouble(readFile[3]),Double.parseDouble(readFile[4]),Double.parseDouble(readFile[5]),Double.parseDouble(readFile[6]),Double.parseDouble(readFile[7]));
                }
                else
                {
                     for(int i = 0; i < readFile[i].length(); i++)
                     {
                         if(readFile[i].equals(""))
                         {
                             readFile[i].replace("","0");   // what to do here ?
                         }

                     }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static void PeriodicTable() {
        for (ChemicalElement element : elements) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DAO.PeriodicTable();  // Just trying to at least print all elements on the list
    }
}
```

EDIT! Adding my .csv file as requested: Not sure about the version of Java,but my IDE is IntelliJ
[image: Not the whole file as it wouldnt find in my snip, but it should give a general idea of what Im dealing with]

Comment: [edit] your question and post part of the CSV file that you are trying to parse. Also, what java version are you using?

Comment: I asked for part of your CSV file so that I could test your code. Excuse me but I don't know how to make a text file on my computer that contains the details in your image. I see you have the _Informed_ badge, which I assume means that you have read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Did you miss (or forget) this part: ___DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.___ - _copy or type the text into the question._

Comment: In your code, you use the comma as the field separator but in the image of your file, the "tab" character appears to be the field separator. Which is it? Is it comma or is it tab?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is as I can see is, the CSV file probably has a column for 'weight' of the element. But value for this column must be empty in at least one of the rows. So when it tries to parse the string value for the weight (or any other double field) it's throwing a numberFormatException. To correct this see if the CSV file adheres to the constraints you enforce on code OR do a round of validation for each row and set the correct default values

Comment: How would I go about setting the value to be of correct type, please ?

Comment: Is the fusion column value for Boron is empty?? Any double field with empty value will throw the Number format exception because it doesn't know how to convert an empty string to a double value

Answer (score 0):

Basically your code has to handle all the unexpected cases including, for example, missing values or invalid values. Parsing a CSV file is not as simple as it at first seems. That is why there are utilities for parsing CSV files such as [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

Refer to my last [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64197188/parsing-correct-type-value-to-a-list-in-java#comment113540574_64197188) to your question. I assume that you are using a comma as the delimiter and I also assumed that the delimiter in the image in your question is a tab and so I changed the tab characters in file **elements2.csv** to commas.

Also, I only took a few lines from the file including the following.

```
Element,Number,Symbol,Weight,Boil,Melt,Density,Vapour,Fusion
Hydrogen,1,H,1.01,20.46,13.96,71,0.45,0.06
Carbon,6,C,12.01,5103.16,4000.16,2260,719.01
Phosphorus,15,P,30.98
Gallium,31,Ga,69.72,2510.16,302.96,5910,,5.61
Niobium,41,Nb,92.91,3573.16,2741.16,8400,,26.8
```

Hydrogen has values for all the fields.
Carbon does not have a value for *Fusion*
Phosphorus only has the first four values.
Gallium is missing the value for *Vapour* (as is Niobium)

First I just checked how many fields are in each line using the following code.

```java
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader("elements2.csv"))) {
    scan.nextLine(); // skip first line
    int counter = 0;
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        counter++;
        String[] readFile = line.split(",");
        System.out.printf("%d. [%d] ^%s^%n", counter, readFile.length, line);
    }
}
catch (IOException xIo) {
    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(xIo);
}
```

Note that the code uses [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) that was added in Java 7.
The above code produced the following output for my "sample" file.
(I use `^` to help me see if there is any leading or trailing whitespace in the string or if it is an empty string.)

```
1. [9] ^Hydrogen,1,H,1.01,20.46,13.96,71,0.45,0.06^
2. [8] ^Carbon,6,C,12.01,5103.16,4000.16,2260,719.01^
3. [4] ^Phosphorus,15,P,30.98^
4. [9] ^Gallium,31,Ga,69.72,2510.16,302.96,5910,,5.61^
5. [9] ^Niobium,41,Nb,92.91,3573.16,2741.16,8400,,26.8^
```

So now that I have an idea of what to expect, I can write the code (for class `DAO`) to read and parse the CSV file. The code includes handling unexpected values.

```java
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DAO {
    private static final int  ELEMENT = 0;
    private static final int  NUMBER = 1;
    private static final int  SYMBOL = 2;
    private static final int  WEIGHT = 3;
    private static final int  BOIL = 4;
    private static final int  MELT = 5;
    private static final int  DENSITY = 6;
    private static final int  VAPOUR = 7;
    private static final int  FUSION = 8;

    public static List<ChemicalElement> elements = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader("elements2.csv"))) {
            scan.nextLine(); // skip first line

            String element;
            int number;
            String symbol;
            double weight;
            double boil;
            double melt;
            double density;
            double vapour;
            double fusion;

            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scan.nextLine();
                String[] readFile = line.split(",");
                if (readFile.length > ELEMENT  &&
                    readFile[ELEMENT] != null  &&
                    !readFile[ELEMENT].isEmpty()) {
                    element = readFile[ELEMENT];
                }
                else {
                    element = ""; // value to use when the CSV file does not contain a value
                }
                if (readFile.length > NUMBER  &&
                    readFile[NUMBER] != null  &&
                    !readFile[NUMBER].isEmpty()) {
                    try {
                        number = Integer.parseInt(readFile[NUMBER]);
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException xNumberFormat) {
                        number = 0; // value to use if value in CSV file is missing or invalid
                    }
                }
                else {
                    number = 0;
                }
                if (readFile.length > SYMBOL  &&
                    readFile[SYMBOL] != null  &&
                    !readFile[SYMBOL].isEmpty()) {
                    symbol = readFile[SYMBOL];
                }
                else {
                    symbol = "";
                }
                if (readFile.length > WEIGHT) {
                    weight = extractDoubleValue(readFile[WEIGHT], 0.0d);
                }
                else {
                    weight = 0.0d;
                }
                if (readFile.length > BOIL) {
                    boil = extractDoubleValue(readFile[BOIL], 0.0d);
                }
                else {
                    boil = 0.0d;
                }
                if (readFile.length > MELT) {
                    melt = extractDoubleValue(readFile[MELT], 0.0d);
                }
                else {
                    melt = 0.0d;
                }
                if (readFile.length > DENSITY) {
                    density = extractDoubleValue(readFile[DENSITY], 0.0d);
                }
                else {
                    density = 0.0d;
                }
                if (readFile.length > VAPOUR) {
                    vapour = extractDoubleValue(readFile[VAPOUR], 0.0d);
                }
                else {
                    vapour = 0.0d;
                }
                if (readFile.length > FUSION) {
                    fusion = extractDoubleValue(readFile[FUSION], 0.0d);
                }
                else {
                    fusion = 0.0d;
                }
                ChemicalElement elem = new ChemicalElement(element,
                                                           number,
                                                           symbol,
                                                           weight,
                                                           boil,
                                                           melt,
                                                           density,
                                                           vapour,
                                                           fusion);
                elements.add(elem);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(xIo);
        }
    }

    public static void periodicTable() {
        for (ChemicalElement element : elements) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }

    private static double extractDoubleValue(String raw, double defaultValue) {
        double value;
        try {
            value = Double.parseDouble(raw);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException | NumberFormatException x) {
            value = defaultValue;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```